What's a word that would describe "Technical Aptitude" as an "attribute"
I'm trying to define a list of attributes that are scorable, such as "Intelligence", "Charisma", etc. One of these attributes would represent "Technical Aptitude". That is, an attribute that represents one's natural ability to learn and adapt to new technologies.
Ideally the word would be short (approximately less than or equal to 10 characters) and clear to understand. There are plenty of words to describe "aptitude", but they all need a clarifier to narrow the scope to technology in particular.
Is there a single word that can represent "Technical Aptitude" as a noun that has the same feeling as other attributes like "Intelligence", "Charisma", etc.?

With SWRs the simple answer is often "No", and that is the case here.

Please [edit] your question and i) clarify what you mean by technical aptitude. Is this about computers? About musical skills? About cooking skills? One can have technical aptitude in all sorts of things. ii) tell us what register the word should be in. Is this formal? Informal? Slang?

If you provide definitions for your single-word attributes, then consider repurposing a word. For example: expertise, mastery, aptitude, knack, facility.
Or try coining a new word. Some ideas: technoskill, technoaptitude, technitude.

+1 :  technoskill

Honestly, I love the idea of a new word, and I kind of like Technitude lol

technodude.....

Technoskill FTW !  Every single one of the 10000s of SWRs on this site, has dozens of suggestions for making up a word.  This is the first good one ever!  Congrats!

But techno is a type of music, and it also reads like tech no skill.

‘Technoskill’ fits in with existing words such as ‘technobabble’, ‘technofear’, ‘technocrat’, and, well, Wiktionary lists 163 of them!

Tech savvy (usually an adjective but can also be used as a noun: "knowledge of or skill with current technology, especially digital technology")

I have the impression that it tends to be used somewhat ironically, though.

A single word that could be used to rate someone's technical ability is

Techiness
WordHippo has
The quality of being techy, or technically oriented

Although mainstream dictionaries give this as an alternative spelling of tetchiness they have

Cambridge Dictionary
techie: someone who knows a lot about computers or other electronic equipment
Merriam-Webster
techie: a person who is very knowledgeable or enthusiastic about technology and especially high technology
Collins
techie: someone who works in a technological industry, especially computing


As opposed to Nesstechie, one who hunts the monster using sonar?

@EdwinAshworth they use Nessietech to locate the monster :)

@EdwinAshworth you're 1000% correct, my bad for adding confusion. I deleted my comment, TY !

If you are referring to computers and other such tech, and if you are OK with a very informal register, you could go with computer-fu. The -fu suffix has entered English, or at least Internet English, as a catch-all for "skill". For instance, if you're good at regular expressions, people might refer to your impressive regex-fu. Possibly the best known example is google-fu to mean one's ability to choose the right search term for a Google Search.
While not a very common term, it will very likely be understood if your audience consists of tech folks.

He's a natural, in the noun sense 4a: "one having natural skills, talents, or abilities". There is the corresponding adjective in the sense 7 of the entry: "having a specified character by nature — a natural athlete, a natural leader". Or a natural techie. Sorry, not a single word ;-).

"a natural" could refer to any skill -- sports, arts, etc. not specifically technology.

A tangential idea, but you could go for the name of something that relates to that aptitude like "science" or "engineering".
Or, more direct, just the word "technology".
I understand that these might be seen as skills rather than attributes - I suppose it depends how you're going to define each. I can't think of anywhere I've seen it before, but if technical aptitude plays a large part in the story, game, or whatever we're considering, I wouldn't be too surprised to see "Vitality/Strength/Endurance/Intelligence/Charisma/Technology/Luck"

For a short pithy word, you could use "chops", which originated in the jazz world to refer to skill in playing an instrument but now is often used to refer to any skill.

Storm Reid‘s acting chops have been apparent against co-stars like
Oprah Winfrey and Zendaya over the years. — Rivea Ruff, Essence, 20
Jan. 2023
Most academic writers just don’t have the chops to make riveting
reading out of the quiltwork of 19th-century farm wives (from the
Boston Phoenix, April 27, 1990)

